# Inner classes in Java with private access

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have an existing class as below:

```
public class A {

    private Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap();
    
    public class B{
        private String name;

        public B(String name) {
            this.name=name;
        }

        //name getter
    }

    public void start() {
        map.put(1, "One"); // example implementation
    }

    public B stop(int val) {
         return new B(map.get(val)); // example implementation
    }

}
```

Now I want to modify class B to return two names i.e. name1 and name2 and want to store a pair of values in the HashMap as below:

```
public class A {

        private Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap();
        
        public class B{
            private String name1;
            private String name2;

            public B(String name1, String name2) {
                this.name1=name1;
                this.name2=name2;
            }

            // getters for name1 and name2
        }

        public void start() {
            Pair<String, String> pair = new Pair("One", "Una");
            map.put(1, pair);
        }

        public B stop(int val) {
             if(map.containsKey(val)) {
                return new B(map.get(val).getKey(), map.get(val).getValue());
             }
             return null;
        }
    
    }
```

Now instead of using Pair I want to use a custom class object. I am new to inner classes in Java. What's the best way to create a inner class given that it would be used to store some set of values in HashMap for internal processing of class A and shouldn't be exposed outside of class A? Any other recommendations on how to do it?

Comment: Why use an inner class? Why not have a class in its own .java file?

Comment: In addition, why don't you use `Map<Integer, B>`, instead of intermediate pair?

Comment: You would be better served to use a nested static class than an inner class (and if you're using a recent Java version, use a record, not a normal class).

Comment: @DevilsHnd - I don't think anyone else be using this class in our project. This is the limited use case we have. So want to keep the access of it limited within class A

Comment: @Chaosfire There will be some additional logic I will be putting in stop method based on the current time which will be use to populate another field of class B. This is WIP, but yeah that's the reason.

Comment: Not to be too pedantic here, but access  level modifiers, such as "private" do not represent a "scope" in Java.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: something like this right within class A?  

private record B (String name1, String name2) {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any other recommendations on how to do it?

Presuming I understand the issue, if you want to return a class then it's existence must be known so the recipient can access the elements.  Even if it is passed as a simple object, the only useful method would be `toString()` since to access the individual elements you must first cast the Object to the class in question.

As far as using an inner class, why not use a `record` (introduced in Java 14)?  It is a simple way to create an immutable class.

- you can access the values directly
- you can use getters.
- it has default `constructor` and `toString()` (`toString` can be overridden if you like)

```
record Pair(String v1, String v2) {}
Pair v = new Pair("ABC", "DEF");
System.out.println(v);       // toString
System.out.println(v.v1());  // getter
System.out.println(v.v2);  // direct access
```

prints

```
Pair[v1=ABC, v2=DEF]
ABC
DEF
```

To override `toString` just put the standard definition between the `{}`